# How to return IQueryable<T> for further querying

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying the PagedList.Mvc library from here

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

which has this usage sample

```
var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize
```

typical implmentations of MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); are along the lines of

```
public IQuerable<T> MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts()
{
   using ( var ctx = new MyCtx() )
   {
       return ctx.MyList().Where( .... );
   }
}
```

which of course has the InvalidOperationException() and DBContext is already disposed message

Looking for best practices on how to return IQueryable which can be used here without issues ?

Comment: This is NOT a typical implementation. Typically you inject a context into a repository class which means that you don't dispose at method level.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I disagree.  Both are useful implementations.  When it's possible to scope the context locally to the method it's an acceptable thing to do, but when the generation of the query goes beyond the scope of that method that's not an option, in such cases you need to adjust the scope of the context such that, wherever it is, it encompasses the lifetime of that query.  Programmers should be able to understand what the lifetime of any given query is and scope the context such that it is at that same "level", no more, no less.

Comment: @Servy: true but in most cases your context lifetime is "per-http-context". Note that he tags the question with asp.net. What you say is a piece of a general theory, he needs a precise guidance for his specific, asp.net scenario.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The lifetime will be something less that "per-http-context", so if you scope your context at that level it's very unlikely to be too narrow.  That said, there can be problems associated with scoping a context at too broad of a scope as well (it will consume more resources for longer).  Whenever possible you should ensure that the lifetime of the context is exactly the same as that of the query, or only the slightest bit larger, rather than just always scoping your contexts at a level you know is well beyond what it needs to be.  Of course, if performance is a non-issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "move up" the scope of your data context:

```
public IQueryable<T> MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(MyCtx context)
{
    return context.MyList().Where( .... );
}
```

Then create the context at the larger scope:

```
using (var ctx = new MyCtx())
{
    var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(ctx);

    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to inject the context into the datasource rather than into each single method of it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The point is that the lifetime of the context needs to be increased to exceed the lifetime of the query, how high you need to go to achieve that can of course vary based on the query.  It may need to be at the scope of that object, or it may not.

Comment: I think that should be IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 4):

The good practice is to keep the lifetime of DbContext as *per HTTP request* by using IoC container, most of IoC containers support HttpRequest lifetime.

So you can leverage the scope of DbContext which allows you to use `IQueryable` on upper layer.

More information which two IoC containers I like: *autofac* and *ninject*.

How [*autofac*](http://autofac.org/) supports MVC in [here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration)

Or how [*NInject*](http://www.ninject.org/) supports MVC in [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3)

If you are new on IoC container, you would suggest you should take a look the basic concept of [dependency injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) from Martin Flower. Then go ahead with one of IoC container you choose.

But, you need to be very careful on how to use `IQueryable` and which layer you should stop support it. If not, the devil on behind, *lazy loading* from entity framework will slow down the performance. One of my rule is do not support `IQueryable` on View.